# Display stock portolio in android with clojure

Tags: android, clojure, stocks

Would writing an Android stock portfolio display app in Clojure be a good learning exercise? I'm totally new to Clojure. My impression is that the functional programming style of Clojure might be better suited for other applications and platforms. For example, I can't find a Clojure based open source project to start from. It looks like I should call a Java charting library such as GraphView and look to port a Java open source stock graphing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing android apps in clojure isn't straightforward, although there are some people working on fixing that (GSOC I think), so you'd learn how hard it is :)

If you want to learn clojure, you better start with something which does not involve android.

If you want to learn android, you better start doing so in java.

Answer (score 2):

It will certainly be a good learning experience, though it may not be a pleasant experience.
Clojure On android is not the most common learning path, though everyone makes their own way, 
so I don't mean to discourage you :)

If your Totally new to Clojure **a webapp is a very popular choice** of first real project (and can be made to work nicely from android). Also check out [4clojure.com](http://www.4clojure.com/)